# getting undefined result when using get function on cloud Firestore in Firebase using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, get

I'm pretty new in Angular. I'm trying to use a get function to return the data in my cloud firestore database in firebase. The response I'm getting is undefined, even though as you can see from the image below, there is definitely data in there. I think maybe the problem is my subscribe function in the component. I've tried many different way, but it's not working.

this is my code:
in service

```
 constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private aff: AngularFireFunctions) {}

 getConfigurations() {
    return this.afs.collection<Configuration>('configurations').valueChanges()  }
```

in my ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection} from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import {AngularFireFunctions} from "@angular/fire/functions";
import {Configuration} from "../../dashboard/dashboard.service";
import {DashboardService} from "../../dashboard/dashboard.service";

@Component({
  templateUrl: './vaccine-codes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vaccine-codes.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class VaccineCodesComponent implements OnInit {

  configurations$: Configuration[];

constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) {

}
  // configurations$ = this.dashboardService.getConfigurations()

  getConfigurations() {
    this.dashboardService
      .getConfigurations()
      .subscribe(res => (this.configurations$ = res)

      );
    console.log(this.configurations$);

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getConfigurations();
  
  }


}
```

these are my classes/interfaces:

```
export interface Configuration {
  ChpPrefix: string;
  Vaccines: { [key: string]: Vaccine[] };
  description: string;

}

export interface Vaccine {
  Codes: string[] | null;
}
```

this is my database:
[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you find the response is undefined?

Comment: I did console.log(this.configurations$). see the image below from dev tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getConfigurations` asynchronously get data. When you call `console.log(this.configurations$)` just after the function, the data still not received.

You have to check response inside `subscribe`.

```
  configurations$: Configuration[]; 
  getConfigurations = () =>
    this.dashboardService
      .getConfigurations()
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.configurations$ = res;
      console.log(this.configurations$);
    });
```

Comment: still undefined. I updated my code according to what you said and put the console log within the function

Comment: You have to put `console.log` inside `subscribe`. I found my code was wrong. `res => (...)` should be `res => {...}`.  I have fixed it.  Please try again.

Comment: If this post helps you, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks again @N.F. I often get messed up with these kinds of functions, i.e. where to put arrows, the brackets, the curly braces. Can someone recommend a good course/tutorial/video with an overview of this?